# Can I call a function in Python from a print statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I'm new to python and I am exploring. Now in the following code, I am trying to call a function from a print statement, is it legal?

```
# My func
def summer(num1,num2):
print "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)

num1 = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = raw_input("Enter another number: ")

print "Again, the summation: %d " % (summer(num1,num2))

print "That is the end of the program."
```

Now is the line

```
 print "Again, the summation: %d " % (summer(num1,num2))
```

valid? I am getting an error.
Can I call a function in this manner, from a string? Thank you.

The error that I get is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfunc.py", line 9, in <module>
  summer(num1,num2)
  File "myfunc.py", line 3, in summer
  print "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)
  TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: Getting "an error", please be specific and mention the exact error you get.

Comment: I have edited the error in the question. The answer has already been provided by @Eric Duminil.

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent the code in your method, and return a String. You also need to convert your strings to integers :

```
def summer(num1,num2):
    return "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (int(num1)+int(num2))

num1 = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = raw_input("Enter another number: ")

print "Again, the summation: %s " % (summer(num1,num2))

print "That is the end of the program."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains this. Moreover, when I am taking raw-input, what is the default format it stores/takes in the data? string? My question is, what are converting into **int** in **int(num1)**

Comment: Raw_input always returns a string, even if the content looks like a number. For arithmetic, you need to convert "3" to 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. To convert a string to a number do this:

```
int(String)
```

after whatever you want to convert to an integer

Therefore, you would do:

```
num1 = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
num1 = int(num1)
```

but a faster way would be:

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

That second to last method can be used if you will use num1 as a string and a number (it will change to a number after int(num1)

Sorry just noticed another flaw. (Edited)

I was curious why you had to show the sum before the numbers were defined, and also wanted to tell you that you dont need the %d in the 3rd line and 3rd to last line, just go ahead and do

```
print "The summation of the numbers is", (num1+num2)
```

Another Flaw (Edit #2)

The last comment changed your `print "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)` to `return "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)`
but the person did not go over it with you. When you do `return`, you make the value of the command what the return value is. Let me give you an example.

```
def MultNumByTwo(num):
    num = num * 2
    return num
print MultNumByTwo(3)
```

This will print six, because `MultNumByTwo` takes `num` which I have made 3 and does `num = num * 2` which gives it a new value of itself times two. Now, when I do  `return num`, `MultNumByTwo` takes on the value of the number after `return`.

Now lets look at your code. When you do `print "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)`, the command has no value. It will just do what it was told which was add these two numbers. Therefore, you can only use it alone because it has become a command. You cannot use it in a print command.

If %d were to take commands in a print command anyways, it would be `Again, the summation: %d` but %d would be `The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)` and the entire command would print

Again, the summation: The summation of the numbers is: (num1+ num2)

Answer (score 0):

Did small modification to your code.
can get `int` values for num1 and num2 by just using `input()`

```
def summer(num1,num2):
    print "The summation of the numbers is: %d " % (num1+num2)
    return num1+num2

num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")

print "Again, the summation: %d " % (summer(num1,num2))
print "That is the end of the program."
```

Output :

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 5
Enter another number: 10
The summation of the numbers is: 15 
Again, the summation: 15 
That is the end of the program.
>>>
```